# Expect executed shell script don't exit

Tags: linux, sh, expect, spawn

I using expect to automate the installation of a software. This is my simplified expect code that I have in my script, but the same problem also happens when I paste it directly in console.

```
expect <<-EOS
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1

#run the command
spawn ./installSoftware.sh

expect "*?Question 1*" { send "N\r" }

expect -ex {Question 2 (default is [RANDOM STRING]):} { send "\r" }

puts "-------------- DONE 1 ---------------"
expect eof
puts "-------------- DONE 2 ---------------"
EOS
```

the installSoftware.sh is a big script that installs packages and many other things. The script have in the last line.

```
echo "----------- Done-----------"
```

The installSoftware.sh scripts works fine when I execute it directly, but when I use it with the expect script, it runs through and show me "done" echo from the last line, but then it stucks. I can see with HTOP that the process of the script is still running, the installSoftware.sh script don't exit.

Any ideas how to debug this? Is this more a problem of the installSoftware.sh script or something related to expect?

What I can tell is, if I remove this line from the installSoftware.sh, it exit my installSoftware.sh as expected, but this is somewhere in the middle of the hugh script.

```
rpm -Uvh --oldpackage --replacepkgs mysoftware.rpm
```

Comment: Don't you think that it could be helpful to show `installSoftware.sh` if the questionable behavior is there?

Comment: 1) use `expect -d` and see if there's any useful info; 2) when it's stuck, use `pstree` to see if `installSoftware.sh` has any child processes running.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells 1.) I tried the -d, but I didn't saw anything useful. Is there a shortcut I can press to get what expect is waiting for? I guess it is the EOF, because the installSoftware.sh process is still running. I will try it again and check if I see something 2.) I have checked it with HTOP, I don't know if this give different results, but there I didn't saw any child processes.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I checked it quickly. this is how PSTREE looks like when it is done.  
─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash───expect─┬─installVC4.sh
                             │      │                             └─{expect}

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I have checked the `expect -d` again. During debugging I get these lines `expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"` `expect: set expect_out(buffer) "OUTPUT FROM THE LAST LINES"`. I don't see this at the end. The last time I see this, is some lines before the last output.

Comment: as your pstree output shows, there's a `installVC4.sh` still running. is it part of `installSoftware.sh`?

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells Forgot to rename it. That is the same file. I will post shortly the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, the problem were inside the RPM package in a script. This example replicate the same issue and will show that the spawn task will stuck at the end without direct indication of a child process.

expect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
    
expect <<-EOS
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
    
#run the command
spawn ./test.sh
    
expect eof
    
EOS
```

test.sh

```
cp -f sleep.sh /tmp
chmod 777 /tmp/sleep.sh
su testuser -c "/tmp/sleep.sh &"
echo "--- DONE ---"
```

sleep.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
   echo "loading..."
   sleep 5
done
```